# Получение формы для post в requests

Tags: python, post, requests

Пишу программу и есть такая задача - получить форму для авторизации на сайте, которая обычно в post запросе видна. К примеру
{
'log': '',
'pwd': '',
'wp-submit': 'Войти',
'redirect_to': 'wp-admin/',
'testcookie': '1'
}
Сама программа работает если предварительно написать форму для авторизации, но хотелось бы автоматизировать.

Comment: так вам надо "получить форму для авторизации на сайте" или "автоматизировать авторизацю"?

Comment: по сути и то и то

Comment: я получаю форму для авторизации и этим автоматизирую ее

Comment: т.е. нужно авторизироваться в админке wordpress средствами requests? а дальше?

Comment: задача такая: я ввожу сайт программа сама находит форму авторизации я пишу только данные для входа и все, но проблема в том что я не знаю как найти автоматически форму авторизации. А админка вордпресс была лишь примером

Comment: "админка вордпресс была лишь примером"... вы же понимаете, что все сайты авторизируют по-разному и код авторизации для wordpress не будет работать на других вэб-ресурсах?

Comment: Автоматически находить форму - это в общем случае невозможно. Есть миллион вариантов, как это может быть реализовано. Можно разве что какие-то эвристики, там искать поле с названием login/username и поле password, и форму в которой они находятся. Но это будет ненадежно.

Comment: Я их хотел узнать может есть какой то способ сначала на сайт кинуть запрос а потом из него как в браузере достать форму для авторизации